# .gitignore hiding senstive information in repository

Tags: git

How do I implement/use a .gitignore to protect/hide sensitive data in my repositories? Im clueless on how to implement it. Any Help at all/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Im trying to implement a .gitignore. I'm expecting it to hide sensitive data in my repos.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `c#` tag is used for questions about code written in C# or about C#'s formal specification.

Comment: You will get more useful information if you can mention what kind of files/data you're thinking about keeping in your repo. Thats because there might be better ways to handle some kinds of sensitive data than keeping it in a repo.

Answer (score 4):

> How do I implement/use a .gitignore to protect/hide sensitive data in my repositories?

You don't - that's not the point of a `.gitignore` file. The point of it is to avoid you putting files into the repository that you don't want to include there in the first place.

So if you have any local files in your clone that you don't want added if you use `git add --all` or similar, then put those filenames in your `.gitignore` file. But that's all it does - it tells git to ignore those files. It *doesn't*  add them to the repository and then hide them from prying eyes.

Comment: It also doesn't effect files that where added previously at all